# Can't execute JavaScripts on Alfresco

Tags: javascript, alfresco-share

This might be extremely simple, but I can;t execute Java Scripts Files on Alfresco Data Dictionary/Script folder. It doesn't give the option to "run" on any of the files. I can image that this is a permission issue, but  I'm log with the Admin account. Is there any particular group that this account might be associated apart from ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS to run scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the scripts from Rule for example. One of the available actions is "Execute script" in which you should see your script within "Data Dictionary/Scripts".

If you plan to play with JS in Alfresco, you should try the [JavaScript Console](http://code.google.com/p/share-extras/wiki/JavascriptConsole) for Share.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was trying to run the scripts through Alfresco Share instead of the explorer App. >.<